# Changing input name value

Tags: jquery, input

Is it possible to change the name value of an input element?

Here is my code but i can set anything but the name.

```
$('#country').change(function(){
    var $country = $(this);
    var $state = $('#state');
    var $county = $("#county");
    if($country.val() != 226){
        $state.attr('name', '');
        $state.closest('p').hide();
        $county.attr('name', 'user[state]');
        $county.closest('p').show();
    }else{          
        $state.attr('name', 'user[state]');
        $state.closest('p').show();
        $county.attr('name', '');
        $county.closest('p').hide();            

    }
});
```

Any ideas why setting a name attr does not work ?

Hope you can advise

Comment: You're trying to set it's name to nothing? What's your goal here?

Comment: instead of your approach, you may also just set the name of state as N/A outside country 226, which is a normal practice on web forms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a shot in the dark here, it seems like you want to prevent these elements from submitting to the server, if that's the case instead of trying to change the `name` attribute, you can set the [`disabled` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12), like this:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
    var $country = $(this), $state = $('#state'), $county = $("#county");
    if($country.val() != 226) {
        $state.attr('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
        $county.attr('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
    } else {
        $state.attr('disabled', false).closest('p').show();
        $county.attr('disabled', true).closest('p').hide();
    }
});
```

When a form element has the `disabled` attribute, it can't be [successful](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#successful-controls), which means it won't be included when you submit it to the server.  So in the above example just give both inputs `name="user[state]"` from the start, and this will exclude the one you don't want from the POST (or GET) that your `<form>` does.

It doesn't answer the question directly, I realize this, but it's another (I think) simpler way to avoid the problem :)  You can shorten this down further by using [`.toggle(bool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) but I think it destroys the example, so I left it uncompressed above, the short version would look like this:

```
$('#country').change(function() {
  var is226 = $(this).val() == 226;
  $('#state').attr('disabled', !is226).closest('p').toggle(is226);
  $("#county").attr('disabled', is226).closest('p').toggle(!is226);
});
```

Comment: Nice response nick. Didn't think of using disabled!!!!. Nice short hand code as well.  Strange though I can seem to set the input to disabled even just by trying in the console window.

Comment: @Lee - Are you saying neither the code above or your console is seeing the element as `disabled`? If so, which browser?

Comment: Just trying to set it in console ie,
$('#county').attr('disabled', false);
$('#county').attr('disabled', true);

The true does not work

Comment: @Lee - When you do `$("#country").attr('disabled')` it doesn't change?

Comment: Disable is fine. Its setting it back to true.  Very wiered

Comment: Just to let you know Nick re-starting firefox resolved the disabled setting !!. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, this is an IE bug. I had to convert the JQuery obj to a string, do the name changing as a string and then create a new jquery object around the html string.

so

```
var form = $('#myForm').html();
form.replace('name', 'newName');
$('#myFormWrapper').html(form);
```

Apparently changing the name attribute is more difficult than it should be :/

Comment: Possibly because IE tends to take any 'name' attributes and auto-create objects of the same name pointing to that DOM element.